# Обновление списка через шаблон

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Имею на входе список объектов [Path1, Path2] - объекты python pathlib, которые хочу преобразовать в строку и дополнить префиксом, используя данное выражение:

```
{%- for path in ld_library_path|default([], false) %}
   {{ envrs.append('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=' + path|string + ':') }}
{%- endfor %}
Environment={{ envrs|join(' ') }}
```

Результат на выходе в строчке Enviroment соответствует ожиданиям, но при этом от каждого элемента цикла получаю записанные None

```
None
None
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Path1:LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Path2
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Желаемый вывод - без None:

```
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Path1:LD_LIBRARY_PATH=Path2
```

Comment: добавление "-" в строку проблему не решает, только убирает перевод строки
{{ envrs.append('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=' + path|string + ':') }}

Answer (score 0):

данную проблему можно решить, если заменить выражение

```
{{ envrs.append('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=' + path|string + ':') }}
```

на

```
{%- if envrs.append('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=' + path|string + ':') %} {% endif %}
```